# How to change Url in IControllerFactory

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a task, that when you, for example, go to Url: /Home/Index, 
and your browser language is set to English it should redirect to /Home_en/Index

For now, I manage to view Index from Home_en controller, but Url stays the same - /Home/Index

I also added a line in Globas.asax:

ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new ControllerFactoryController());

```
 public IController CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, string 
      controllerName)

        Type targetType = null;
        string[] languages = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserLanguages;



        if (languages[0] == "en-US")
        {
            requestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] = "Home_en";
            targetType = typeof(Home_enController);

        }
        else
        {
            requestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] = "Home_pl";
            targetType = typeof(Home_plController);

        }

        IController controller = Activator.CreateInstance(targetType) as IController;

        return controller;
    }
```

How to make that in Url it will be shown as /Home_en/Index